# Upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 stuck at Restoring Previously Installed Packages

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

As the title says, I have tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 by LiveUSB and the install has frozen at 'Restoring Previously Installed Packages'. Has been stuck at this point for almost 2 hours.. When I expand the terminal for the install details, nothing seems to be downloading (which could cause this time delay) and the only activity is from when I connected and disconnected from the wireless network..

Any suggestions?

Comment: I got this as well.  However, in my case it did complete some hour or two later, so I have no idea why this took so long.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar symptoms on a new laptop while installing 16.04LTS. But slightly worse in that it was a total freeze / zero response. Live DVD seemed to work ok though. Found inspiration in the following article:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

In short:- disable secure boot AND uefi in the bios. Then fresh install.

(hardware was Intel Pentium Quad + Integrated HD Graphics)